# SciKit Gradient Boosting - How to combine predictions with initial table?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a gradient-boosting model to predict future scores in fantasy football - for now only looking at the 2 previous rounds. Currently, if a player is expected to score more than 6 points, the model would return '1', otherwise '0' - indicating whether the player would be a good captain choice or not.

In my original table i have player-name and round information to give context, but i removed these when training the algorithm. My question is, once the model makes a prediction - how can i show this prediction in combination with the player name, for example:

PlayerA - captain prediction = 1

etc.

```
y = ds.isCaptain
GB_table = ds.drop(['Player', 'Round', 'isCaptain', 'Points'], axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(GB_table, y, test_size=0.2)

baseline = GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.01,n_estimators=1500,max_depth=4, min_samples_split=40, min_samples_leaf=7,max_features=4 , subsample=0.95, random_state=10)

baseline.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictors=list(X_train)
feat_imp = pd.Series(baseline.feature_importances_, predictors).sort_values(ascending=False)
feat_imp.plot(kind='bar', title='Importance of Features')
plt.ylabel('Feature Importance Score')

print('Accuracy of GBM on test set: {:.3f}'.format(baseline.score(X_test, y_test)))
pred=baseline.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, pred))
```

The above shows me the predicted results, but unfortunately since I removed the player name and round information from the `GB_table`, I can no longer understand from who/which round the prediction is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using pandas DataFrames, in which case it's quite straightforward.

The index numbers in your X_train and X_test DataFrames will correspond to the index in your original 'ds' DataFrame.

Try:

```
pred = baseline.predict(X_test)
pred_original_data = ds.iloc[X_test.index]
pred_original_data['prediction'] = pred
```

Answer (score 1):

You could drop the player column and other fields after `train_test_split`.

Here is my suggestion

```
y = ds.isCaptain

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(ds, y, test_size=0.2)

baseline = GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.01, n_estimators=1500,max_depth=4, min_samples_split=40, min_samples_leaf=7,max_features=4 , subsample=0.95, random_state=10)


baseline.fit(X_train.drop(['Player', 'Round', 'isCaptain', 'Points'], axis=1),y_train)

X_test_input = X_test.drop(['Player', 'Round', 'isCaptain', 'Points']
score = baseline.score(X_test_input, y_test))
print('Accuracy of GBM on test set: {:.3f}'.format(score)
X_test['prediction'] = baseline.predict(X_test_input)
print(classification_report(y_test, X_test['prediction']))
```